# Looking for a Good guide on how to setup a new IP scope in SBS 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, dhcp

I'm looking for a very comprehensive guide on how to setup a DHCP IP scope, for a phone and PC network on Microsoft Small Business Server 2008.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up DHCP scopes on SBS 2008 isn't any different than on a regular Server 2008 machine. Find a good guide on DHCP for Server 2008 and you've got your answer. For example, the following:

http://www.windowsreference.com/windows-server-2008/how-to-setup-dhcp-server-in-windows-server-2008-step-by-step-guide/